# Howto publish private projects to Sinopia (npm adduser for private registry fails)

Tags: node.js, npm, package-managers

Ok so I finally managed to get a private npm registry using Sinopia. **But I cannot publish anything to it.**

> TL;DR: Sinopia does not support *npm adduser*, but has its own user
>   management. Also npm needs a valid user created before *npm publish*
>   through *npm adduser*, which fails because the internal Sinopia server
>   throws an error at the unsupported command....

#### How does one use Sinopia as a private registry with proper users and passwords

1. create a global user in npmjs.org, and then another with the same password in Sinopia?
2. Or is there an easier way to tell npm to just use a fixed user/pass.
3. Or even better prompt me somehow for username and password?
4. something else?

---

Synopsis:

Sinopia does not depend on Couch.DB and will hapilly fetch packages it does not already have from a master (default is the global npmjs.org).

Sinopia starts perfectly and is configured to listen on all interfaces. It works wonders in serving packages to

```
npm install
```

I even configured ~/.npmrc to always point to the internal registry.

All projects' package.json file is set to

```
  ....
  "publishConfig" : {
     "registry" : "http://internal-npm:4873"
  },
  ....
```

Also I managed to add custom users in sinopia by manipulating the config.yaml with the help of js-yaml

```
crypto.createHash('sha1').update('theBigPassword').digest('hex')
```

Now I am stuck at

```
npm --registry=http://internal-npm:4873 --ca=null publish
```

After a long wait I get:

```
npm ERR! need auth auth and email required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-18-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "--registry=http://internal-npm:4873" "--ca=null" "publish"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ciprian/workspace/netop-npm
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ciprian/workspace/netop-npm/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The business end of the log file tells me that the user is not optional

```
86 error need auth auth and email required for publishing
86 error need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
87 error System Linux 3.11.0-18-generic
88 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "--registry=http://internal-npm:4873" "--ca=null" "publish"
89 error cwd /home/ciprian/workspace/netop-npm
90 error node -v v0.10.15
91 error npm -v 1.2.18
92 error code ENEEDAUTH
93 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Now, the **chicken and egg** issue is that Sinopia does not support `npm adduser`, but has its own user management like I mentioned above. Also npm needs a valid user created through `npm adduser`, which fails because the internal Sinopia server throws an error at the unsupported command.

Answer (score 25):

First of all, it is not "chicken and egg" problem.

"npm adduser" does two things:

1. it creates a new user on the remote server, or verifies that it exists
2. it adds _auth to your .npmrc

Sinopia will complain if user doesn't exist, but if it does, it'll happily report success.

---

So, what you have to do is this:

1. add user/pass to config.yaml (see josh's answer) and restart sinopia server
2. run `npm adduser --registry http://internal-npm:4873/`

Yes, "adduser" command is confusing, because it won't actually add a new user. It'll just verify that user exists in config.

If you want, you can use "npm login" command. It is less confusing even though it does exactly the same thing. :)

---

Second of all, add this to your package.json:

```
"publishConfig": {
  "registry": "http://internal-npm:4873/"
}
```

This way npm won't publish it to the public registry anymore, even if it's a default one.

---

And lastly, you can't use two registries (npmjs and your private one) at the same time with the same npmrc. It's even [less secure](https://github.com/rlidwka/yapm/blob/master/changes/multireg-sec.md) than you think.

It's okay in most cases, but if you **have** to use both of them (for example, you maintain public and private packages at the same time), use [yapm](https://github.com/rlidwka/yapm) instead of npm and write something like this to your .npmrc:

```
[registries."https://registry.npmjs.org/"]
_auth = (your auth string for public registry)

[registries."http://internal-npm:4873/"]
_auth = (your auth string for private registry)
always-auth = true
```

It'll prevent exposing your passwords to public registry in all cases.

Comment: +1 for the publishConfig comment. Didn't know we could do this.

Comment: I just wasted a bit of time on this...the generated `.npmrc` from `npm adduser` switches a bit between needing `http://` before the private registry url, and not needing the protocol prefix...long story short, if you forget to put `http://` in you package's publishConfig section, you will get an invalid `npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH` error message, where `publish.js` drops all authentication information from your request.

Comment: Seems like Sinopia now supports adding users by simply issuing `npm adduser --registry=http://localhost:4873` . No need to edit config.yaml anymore.

Answer (score 7):

The Sinopia [README tells you exactly what to do](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia#adding-a-new-user).

> ### Adding a new user
>
> There is no utility to add a new user but you can at least use node on the command-line to generate a password. You will need to edit the config and add the user manually.
>
> Start node and enter the following code replacing 'newpass' with the password you want to get the hash for.
>
> ```
> $ node
> > crypto.createHash('sha1').update('newpass').digest('hex')
> '6c55803d6f1d7a177a0db3eb4b343b0d50f9c111'
> > [CTRL-D]
> ```

Insert the new user into your config.yaml file.

You then run `npm adduser` to login.  (`adduser` is the command used for both account creation and login; sinopia does not support the creation part.)

Comment: npm adduser failed because the npmjs.org server was out of order. Which is precisely why I wanted a local repository. Still this is NOT what I wanted: I do not want the user/password to be valid for the global npm repository. Isn't there a way to add a user manually in ~/.npmrc without it actually making it in the global CouchDB ?

Comment: What is not said in the doc is that you have to add the same user and the same password in both systems, which I profoundly dislike.

Comment: No, you don't.  You create a user and a password hash and add it to config.yaml, then restart Sinopia.  You then use `adduser` and provide the same username and plaintext password to login to your private server.  It need not be the same as an account that exists on the public npm.

Comment: ...in other words, `npm adduser --registry=http://localhost:4873` worked for me when I typed a username and password that I had added to config.yaml.

Comment: Ok, all my issues are traced back to the fact that npmjs.org was not working most of the past few days. Also I didn't know how to add a user/pass hash in .npmrc without it being connected to npmjs.org, now I know: _auth = base64(user+':'+pass)

Comment: Seems like Sinopia now supports adding users by simply issuing `npm adduser --registry=http://localhost:4873` . No need to edit config.yaml anymore.

Answer (score 4):

*Option 1 works*, but I'm not really happy with it. So I'll keep on searching

YES, if I add a valid npmjs.org user, then swith the repo:

```
npm config set registry http://internal-npm:4873/
```

The publish command will work if the same user/pass exists in Sinopia

```
npm publish --registry=http://internal-npm:4873/
```

**The downside** is that if someone forgets to explicitly set the private registry, the publish will 100% work on the global npmjs.org, which would be a disaster.

Comment: To avoid the downside you mention, add the `publishConfig` mentioned in [alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22702329/3666800) below.  This restricts where the package will be published within the package itself.  So even if someone forgets to set the registry for npm, the publish will still go to the correct registry for that project.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.13, Sinopia does support the creation of a new user through

npm adduser --registry example.com:port

For more details see: [HOW TO CREATE A NEW SINOPIA USER](http://resolvethis.com/how-to-create-a-new-sinopia-user/)

Answer (score 0):

Me help contributor of sinopia :)
See here:
https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/230#issuecomment-91825660